# Is there something I'm missing about tuples?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn Python from ''Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'' and I came across a program which I don't clearly understand.

```
phone_regex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?                        # separator
    (\d{3})                           # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)                         # separator
    (\d{4})                           # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?    # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)



matches = []
for groups in phone_regex.findall(text):
    print('here')
    phone_number = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phone_number += ' x' + groups[8]
        matches.append(phone_number)
```

This is obviously not the whole thing, but I don't understand how IS there a groups[8] when there are only 6 groups in the regex. Additionally, while I do know the first group, group[0], is supposedly the first one, I don't really understand how...Does it just work like that, when there's one big tuple containing multiple tuples, the big one is considered the first one when indexed ?

This is obviously not the whole thing, but I don't understand how IS there a groups[8] when there are only 6 groups in the regex. Additionally, while I do know the first group, group[0], is supposedly the first one, I don't really understand how...Does it just work like that, when there's one big tuple containing multiple tuples, the big one is considered the first one when indexed ?

Also, how do the for loops here work exactly ? What are they looping ? I thought adding something like groups=groups[0:] was necessary for iterations to actually be different from one another in cases like this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 8 groups

Answer (score 0):

Note that some capturing groups have **embedded** capturing groups,
which are also counted.

Hence:

- `(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?` - is group 1.
- `\(\d{3}\)` - is **not** an embedded group, since both parentheses
  are quoted and are treated literally.
- *separator*, *first 3 digits*, second *separator* and
  *last 4 digits* are groups 2 thru 5.
- `(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?` - is group 6 (with 2 embedded groups).
- `(ext|x|ext.)` - is group 7.
- `(\d{2,5})` - is group 8.

To see what has been captured by each group, run:

```
text = '123-456-9876 ext 22, (123)-456-9876'
for groups in phone_regex.findall(text):
    print(f'Whole match: {groups[0]}')
    n = 1
    for grp in groups[1:]:
        print(f'{n}: {grp:5}', end=', ')
        n += 1
    print()
```

The result I got was:

```
Whole match: 123-456-9876 ext 22
1: 123  , 2: -    , 3: 456  , 4: -    , 5: 9876 , 6:  ext 22, 7: ext  , 8: 22   , 
Whole match: (123)-456-9876
1: (123), 2: -    , 3: 456  , 4: -    , 5: 9876 , 6:      , 7:      , 8:      ,
```

And answering to your question in the comment:
I think you should avoid costructs like *groups = groups[1:]*.
Syntactically it is correct, but this way you attempt to mess around
with the results of what has been found.
You can **read** *groups[1:]* like in my code above but don't attempt to
**save** there anything.

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot !

I do have another question though, about the four loop. Shouldn't there be something like group=group[1:] ( I know this isn't the correct syntax, but you get the point ), which would progress the loop actually ? The way it is now, each iteration seems to be the same when nothing changes...